# How to prevent debugging code to be compiled for prod

Tags: angular, ionic3

In an Ionic app I have some parts that need user interaction (it is an Alert 
 that triggers things like http requests, video rewards, etc) Since I do not want to make this interaction every time I am coding a new feature in that path I have this snippet:

```
if (this.isDevMode) {
    alert.addInput({
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'this should not be in production',
        value: 'this should not be in production',
        checked: false,
        disabled: !this.isDevMode
    });
}
```

The thing is even when I do not see that option in the alert when I build the app with --prod I do see that code minified:

```
this.isDevMode && e.addInput({
    type: "radio",
    label: "this should not be in production",
    value: "this should not be in production",
    checked: !1,
    disabled: !this.isDevMode
}),
```

Is there a way to three shake this in a prod environment ?